# Google maps api generates an error in Chrome suddenly since a few days. Not in firefox

Tags: google-maps, maps

The map, the dierction and distance is correctly displayed but the script stop and the rest of my website isn´t shown in Chrome.
What can it be?

I found the reason for the error.
The code below is correct.
This one:

```
    <script    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>

     don`t likes that:

    <script  src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCsWAeW4gm1P1f-pyYhiAkkE&libraries=places'></script>

 in one file.

 I put the first one in a different file. Everything works fine again.
 The only question is why the error came suddenly, over night?
```

Code:

```js
function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.744006,8.820419),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-    canvas'), mapOptions);

    var land = document.getElementById('stland').value;
    /* if ( document.getElementById('ziland').value != land ) */  
    //alert(land);

    var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */ ( document.getElementById('start'));
    var options = {
        types: ['geocode'],
        types: ['(cities)'],
        componentRestrictions: {country: land}
    };
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);

    var land2 = document.getElementById('ziland').value;
    var input2 = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('end'));
    var options2 = {
        types: ['geocode'],
        types: ['(cities)'],
        //regions:['postal_code'],
        componentRestrictions: {country: land2}
    };   
    var autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input2,options2);

    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
        infowindow.close();
        marker.setVisible(false);
        input.className = '';

        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        if (!place.geometry) {
            // Inform the user that the place was not found and return.
            input.className = 'notfound';
            return;
        }

        // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
        }

        marker.setIcon(/** @type {google.maps.Icon} */({
            url: place.icon,
            size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
        }));
        marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
        marker.setVisible(true);

        var address = '';

        if (place.address_components) {
            address = [
                (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
            ].join(' ');
        }

        infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
    // Autocomplete.
    function setupClickListener( types) {
        var radioButton = document.getElementById('changetype-geocode');
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(radioButton, 'click', function() {
        autocomplete.setTypes(types);
        });
    }

    setupClickListener('changetype-all', []);
    setupClickListener('changetype-establishment', ['establishment']);
    setupClickListener('changetype-geocode', ['geocode']);
} 

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize1() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

    var frankfurt = new google.maps.LatLng(50.127182,8.678398);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom:5,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: frankfurt
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function() {
        computeTotalDistance(directionsDisplay.directions);
    });
}

function calcRoute() {
    //setTimeout( 3000);
    var start = document.getElementById('stland').value + ' ' + document.getElementById('stplz').value + ' ' + document.getElementById('start').value;
    var end = document.getElementById('ziland').value + ' ' + document.getElementById('ziplz').value + ' ' + document.getElementById('end').value;
    var request = {
        origin:start,
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
        }
    });
}

function computeTotalDistance(result) {
    var total = 0;
    var myroute = result.routes[0];

    for (i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
        total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
    }
    total = total / 1000;

    //document.getElementById('entfernung').innerHTML = total + ' km';
    document.anfrager1.entfernung.value = total + ' km';
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the error.

Comment: I found the reason for the error.